# HTML in pure Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there such a gem exists for writing rails view helpers or even views? If not, what would be the starting point for such a gem?

```
div class: 'header' do
  h1 { 'Hello World' }
  a href: 'http://google.com', class: 'button' do
    'Google'
  end
end
```

Inspired by how recent javascript front-end libraries implement component based views using pure javascript functions, such as: React, Vue.js etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Arbre](https://github.com/activeadmin/arbre) will do the job. 
It was extracted from widely used [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) gem as independent solution for such needs.

A simple example from project's README:

```
html = Arbre::Context.new do
  h2 "Why is Arbre awesome?"

  ul do
    li "The DOM is implemented in ruby"
    li "You can create object oriented views"
    li "Templates suck"
  end
end

puts html.to_s # =>
```

will render the following:

```html
<h2>Why is Arbre awesome?</h2>
<ul>
  <li>The DOM is implemented in ruby</li>
  <li>You can create object oriented views</li>
  <li>Templates suck</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 9):

Maybe [Markaby](http://markaby.rubyforge.org/) will help you, which lets you generate HTML through Ruby.

An example from the official docs:

```
  require 'markaby'

  mab = Markaby::Builder.new
  mab.html do
    head { title "Boats.com" }
    body do
      h1 "Boats.com has great deals"
      ul do
        li "$49 for a canoe"
        li "$39 for a raft"
        li "$29 for a huge boot that floats and can fit 5 people"
      end
    end
  end
  puts mab.to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code looks very similar to [HAML](https://github.com/haml/haml):

```
#app/views/model/your_view.haml
.header
  %h1 Hello World
  = link_to "Google", "http://google.com", class: "button"
```

If you're looking for a way to clear up your views, that may be a good place to begin.

---

`@Meeh` looks like he has a good answer; if you wanted another opinion, I would start looking into [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode).

To my understanding, pseudocode is basically a way to create a "application-level" functionality of a deeper level. For example...

```
#app/helpers/view_helper.rb
class ViewHelper
   def a approved_site, *options
      return "Site not valid" unless Site.exists? name: approved_site.to_s

      site = Site.find_by name: approved_site.to_s
      options.extract_args!

      link_to site.name, site.url, options #-> ruby automatically returns the last line
   end
end
```

... this would allow you to call:

```
#app/views/controller/view.haml
= a :google, class: "button"
```

--

If you wanted to make that into a full-scale front-end framework, you'd need a collection of "base" functions. On top of those functions, you'd have more specific implementations, such as:

```
#app/helpers/base_helper.rb
class BaseHelper
    def meta type, *args
        types   = %i(js css title link keywords author description robots favicon)
        options = args.join(', ')

        # Return Values
        case type
            when :title
                Haml::Engine.new("%title #{options}").render
            end
        end
    end
end

#app/helpers/meta_helper.rb
class MetaHelper
   def title value
     meta :title, value
   end
end
```

Comment: Okay I just realized this might not be on topic (you want pure ruby implementation). I'll happily delete if it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I think you want react.rb (http://reactrb.org)  Does everything Abre does, plus can deal with client side interactions as well (if you need it to.)

Answer (score 0):

The [dom](https://rubygems.org/gems/dom) gem that I have developed does exactly what you wanted to. Using it, you can do things like:

```
require "dom"
["foo".dom(:span, class: "bold"), "bar"].dom(:div).dom(:body).dom(:html)
# => "<html><body><div><span class=\"bold\">foo</span>bar</div></body></html>"
```